# Outlook addon to export calendar

Tags: ide, outlook-addin

I am planning to write a outlook addon that exports calendar and possibly send it as HTTP post to my server. I am good in java/j2ee technologies. But i don't know vc++ or c#. 
Is there a IDE (similar to eclipse) that i can use to design the plugin and code it to do this task efficiently. Please note I don't work on windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can only use Visual Studio and Delphi to write COM Add-ins.